# Change width of menu canvas of Foundation

Tags: menu, zurb-foundation-5

I am using the framework foundation and is very useful.
I wanted to know how you can change the width of the canvas menu.
Use escusicamente css.
Thank

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the scss version of Foundation it's as easy as changing `$off-canvas-width: rem-calc(250);` in your `settings.scss` file.

If you are using css you need to change the width of the `.left-off-canvas-menu` and `.move-right > .inner-wrap` `transform`.
I suggest you override specificity by adding a new class to `.left-off-canvas-menu` and `off-canvas-wrap`, something like `<div class="my-site off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>` and `<div class="my-site left-off-canvas-menu>`

Then CSS:

```
.my-site.move-right > .inner-wrap {
    webkit-transform: translate3d(newwidth, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(newwidth, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(newwidth, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(newwidth, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(newwidth, 0, 0);
}
```

and

```
.my-site.left-off-canvas-menu {
    width: newwidth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Foundation 6, I used the following code to change the width of the off-canvas menu (using a variable):

```
$offcanvas-right-size: 315px;

.is-open-right {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-$offcanvas-right-size);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-$offcanvas-right-size);
    transform: translateX(-$offcanvas-right-size);
}

.off-canvas.position-right {
  width: $offcanvas-right-size;
  right: -$offcanvas-right-size;
}
```

I had left and right menus and wanted the right to be smaller.

Comment: I'm using the CSS version and would like to dynamically set the menu canvas width to window.innerWidth using JavaScript. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

On an addition to the answer above (Rep blocks comment function)
Also made with foundation 6

The thing Lee forgot to address is that the second div is nested into the off-canvas position-left canvas, at least in my code
The first class is for the size of the off-canvas menu and the second to also move the content

```
.is-open-left {
-webkit-transform: translateX(125px);
-ms-transform: translateX(125px);
transform: translateX(125px);
}



.off-canvas-menu{
padding-left:125px;
}
```